# File only loads on Simulator not on real device (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, file, swift3, localization

I am trying to get a localized JSON file from my project. With the following code everything works great on Simulator but NOT on real devices.

```
 let supportedLocalizations = ["en", "de"]

    let currentLanguage : String

    if let locale = Locale.current.languageCode, supportedLocalizations.contains(locale) {
        currentLanguage = locale
    } else {
        currentLanguage = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion") as! String
    }
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "document", withExtension: "json", subdirectory: nil, localization: currentLanguage)!
    let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
```

Does anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a wrong approach. Assuming you have a json document for each supported language, why dont you just bake the language into the filename, and then load it like this:

```
var json : NSDictionary!
let fileName = "document_" + currentLanguage
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName,                        
          withExtension: "json") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
        do {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as
                    Data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        } catch {
            print("Unable to parse  \(fileName).json")             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: iPhone has this URL: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/F2BC4739-F484-4435-AAA6-4BA5E0724F08/Remember_The_Bill.app/document.json

Comment: I know that this is wrong but I don't know how to fix it